# Adding multiple values to an environment in registry and retrieving in Java application

Tags: java, environment-variables, registry, procrun

I am using procrun to run a java application as a service.

I used following to set path:

```
set PATH="dir1;dir2;%PATH%"
procrun.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++Environment PATH=%PATH%
```

which updates environment value in registry as:

[image]

But, in my Java application when I try to get the value of **PATH**:

```
System.getenv("PATH")
```

I get only the first value ( i.e. dir1 in above case. If I set the path to `dir2;dir1;%PATH%`, I get only dir2)

Am I retrieving in a wrong way or setting in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the lack of quoting in the `--Environment` option:

> List of environment variables that will be provided to the service in the form key=value. They are separated using either # or ; characters. If you need to embed either # or ; character within a value put them inside single quotes.

(cf. [Procrun documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html)).

Since Windows expands `%PATH%` to a list of `;`-separated paths, you need to use:

```
procrun.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++Environment 'PATH=%PATH%'
```

or `PATH='%PATH'` if you prefer. The single quote character is stripped from the parameter string after breaking it into a `;`-separated list of parameters (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/ff1c7eb20d90d4cf8bcd5534c24e8ed010ae63e0/src/native/windows/src/cmdline.c#L213)). Hence there might be a problem if you have single quotes in the name of a folder.

**Edit**: procrun also accepts quoting through double quotes (which are not stripped) and your `PATH` variable contains quotes, but the [magic of cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/11748454) strips them away.