# TOMCAT: quote < ' > in CATALINA_HOME environment variable causing load error?

Tags: windows, tomcat, environment-variables, procrun

I'm trying to install tomcat as a service using service.bat in the following path :
C:\Program Files\text with' quote\Tomcat

but I keep getting the following error :
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\text with quote\Tomcat\conf\logging.properties; (The system cannot find the path specified)**

as you can see from the error message the ' is being ignored and thus keeping some files from being found/loaded properly.

If I switch to a path without a quote, everything works well. Is there a way around this as I need to include a ' in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the way **Procrun** parses its [command line parameters](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html#Command_line_parameters). In those parameters which accept lists of values (`++DependsOn`, `++Environment`, `++JvmOptions`, `++JvmOptions9`, `++StartParams` and `++StopParams`) single quotes `'` are stripped after the parameter value has been split into single values. There is no way to quote them (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/ff1c7eb20d90d4cf8bcd5534c24e8ed010ae63e0/src/native/windows/src/cmdline.c#L213)).

Therefore the `++JvmOptions` parameter used in `service.bat` is interpreted as follows (one value per line):

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Scarlett oHara;-Dcatalina.base=C:\Scarlett oHara
-Dignore.endorsed.dirs=C:\Scarlett oHara\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Scarlett oHara\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Scarlett oHara\conf\logging.properties;
```

You might notice that some entries are joined by `;`, due to the `'` unintentional quoting.

The only way to fix this is to start **Prunmgr** (the executable renamed as `tomcat*w.exe`) and fix them in the *"Java"* tab:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\Scarlett o'Hara
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Scarlett o'Hara
-Dignore.endorsed.dirs=C:\Scarlett o'Hara\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Scarlett o'Hara\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Scarlett o'Hara\conf\logging.properties;
```

or work directly on the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0` registry keys.

**See also**:

- a similar problem due to quoting: [Adding multiple values to an environment in registry and retrieving in Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55937493/11748454)